# R: Count how many values are between two maximum ones

Tags: r, count, max

A relative simply question: we got this vector

```
numbers <- c(22, 16, 18, 15, 26, 21, 19, 25, 16, 27, 18, 16, 19, 28)
```

Is there any easy way to measure the number of values between the last maximum one and the new one? e.g.: between 22 and 26 there would be 4 intermediary values; between 26 and 27 there are 5...and so on untill the last one. These numbers I want to store into another vector with the `append` function.

Thanks and happy holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
table(cummax(numbers)) 

22 26 27 28 
 4  5  4  1
```